# How does one create constants in Tcl?

Tags: constants, tcl

I have seen the use of *set* keyword in tcl often. This cannot be used to create constant. How does one create constant in tcl which can then be used by other procedures?

Comment: Some discussion at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, most of the uses of constants fall into several categories:

1. enumeration values
2. magical numbers
3. looping control factors
4. scaling factors

In Tcl, for the first case you'd usually just use the name instead of mapping it to an integer, with integer mappings only being applied in the cases that need them. Even bit sets can be handled that way, substituting a list of names for the set of bits (and the name being present in the list is equivalent to the bit being set). Tcl's C API has relevant functions for helping with this, specifically `Tcl_GetIndexFromObj()`.

Magical values are usually best locked away close to the code that handles them. If I was interfacing to hardware, I'd not let the magic values appear at all at the script level (since I'd have the binding code written in C).

Looping control factors are often best represented as default values for procedure arguments, as they are things that you want to sometimes override. But they're often not as needed once custom control structures are available, and they fit a lot more into the Tcl style of working.

Scaling factors are the case where constants might be useful. I tend to simulate those by just using a global or namespace variable and plain old not assigning to it from elsewhere. ***I'd be quite interested in having code to allow constants*** (specifically variables that can't be assigned to) ***as a standard feature,*** but we don't have that right now.

Once those cases are covered, what remain tend to be unimportant constants. After all, there's almost no need to calculate the sizes of things for allocation and stuff like that, and things like positional binding in SQL statements are discouraged within TDBC in favour of binding by name (an awful lot easier to get right).

---

A simple way of making a constant is to put a write trace on a variable so that whenever it is written to, it is reset back to its constant value.

```
set CONSTANT 123
trace add variable CONSTANT write {apply {args {
    global CONSTANT
    # Reset to the constant value; write traces are after the fact
    set CONSTANT 123
    # Make the write give an error
    error "may not change constant"
}}}
```

Comment: Have I missed any major categories of constant?

Comment: ... only the issue of `unset` and unset traces: see my `readOnly` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846341/triggering-an-error-on-unsetting-a-traced-variable